# Parse rgb color values as integers through method call

Tags: android

The title says it all.

```
switch (colorChosen) {
    case "Red":
        setEverythingColors(255,0,0,colorChosen);
    case "Brown":
        setEverythingColors(165,42,42,colorChosen);
    case "Orange":
        setEverythingColors(255,165,0,colorChosen);
    case "Blue":
        setEverythingColors(0,0,255,colorChosen);
    case "Green":
        setEverythingColors(0,128,0,colorChosen);
    case "Purple":
        setEverythingColors(128,0,128,colorChosen);
    case "Pink":
        setEverythingColors(246,171,205,colorChosen);
    case "Yellow":
        setEverythingColors(255,255,0,colorChosen);
    case "Grey":
        setEverythingColors(128,128,128,colorChosen);
}
```

and the setEverythingColors method is this

```
public void setEverythingColors(int c1, int c2, int c3, String color){
    backgroundColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(c1,c2,c3));
    colorTitle.setText(color);
}
```

For some reason the build is successful and i get no errors or warnings but whichever the case, the color is never being set and i'm pulling my hair over here!

What might be the case??

Comment: You don't say what 'backgroundColor' is - some sort of View, I suppose.
You probably have some sort of layout issue where the entire view is obscured by another (child?) view, so that you never see the background.

Comment: I just posted he part of the code where my problem is. backgroundColor reflects to a button which is defined before the switch and is as 
backgroundColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theColorButton);

Answer (score 1):

switch-case can work String if it is constant, your code has working but you forget break, and default. You can retry:

```
switch (colorChosen) {
        case "Red":
            setEverythingColors(255, 0, 0, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Brown":
            setEverythingColors(165, 42, 42, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Orange":
            setEverythingColors(255, 165, 0, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Blue":
            setEverythingColors(0, 0, 255, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Green":
            setEverythingColors(0, 128, 0, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Purple":
            setEverythingColors(128, 0, 128, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Pink":
            setEverythingColors(246, 171, 205, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Yellow":
            setEverythingColors(255, 255, 0, colorChosen);
            break;
        case "Grey":
            setEverythingColors(128, 128, 128, colorChosen);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.

```
case "Red":
case "Brown":
etc..
```

was the problem. I was referring to the string in the same way as i would refer to integers.

I can't say `colorChosen=="Red"` because it is a string.

I changed my switch statement to if statements and used `colorChose.equals("Red")` instead and that solved the problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if this resolved your issue.  All pages should be progressed to a system-recognized resolution.   Final outcomes may be: answer acceptance, question closure, or page deletion.  Please tend to all of your questions.